# Problemas para ejecutar SSH en un servidor remoto desde PHP

Tags: php, php7, consola, ssh

Estoy intentando ejecutar dos comandos ssh desde un script php, me ha funcionado cuando intento ejecutar 1 solo comando, pero 2 no me da, necesito arrancar el rails de un servidor remoto desde php, he colocado la autentificación con contraseña y todo excelente cuando ejecuto 1 solo comando, pero 2 no me da. Ya que necesito primero entrar en un sub-directorio para luego ejecutar el comando "rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -d" allí.

el comando que necesito ejecutar es este:
cd diccionario && rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -d

desde la consola del servidor me ejecuta bien, pero desde el php no.

Estoy usando php 7.3, en apache.

Y el servidor remoto donde intento ejecutar los comando  es ubuntu 18.04

Este es el código que estoy usando

````
```<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
````

class Rails_diccionario extends CI_Controller{

```
public function es()
{
    

    $Usuario = 'ubuntu';
    $host = 'example.com';
    $clave = 'contraseña';
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
// ejemplo inicie sesión en 54.145.196.46 en el puerto 22
if(!($con = ssh2_connect("$host", 22))){
    echo "Fallo: incapaz de establecer conexión\n";
} else {
    // intente autenticarse con el nombre de usuario root o ubuntu segun sea el caso y contraseña, se debe hablitar uso de contraseña
    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "$Usuario", "$clave")) {
        echo "Fallo: incapaz de autenticar\n";
        
    } else {
        // Mensaje, estamos dentro!
        
        echo "bien: iniciado sesión...\n";
        

        // Ejecutar un comando
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'cd diccionario && rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -d' ))) 
                               
        {
                        
            echo "fallo: no se puede ejecutar el comando\n";
            
        } else {
            // recopilar datos de retorno del comando
            stream_set_blocking($stream, false);
            $data = "";
            while ($buf = fread($stream,14096)) {
                $data .= $buf;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
}```

Comment: Revisa la documentación de ssh2_exec. El Stream de salida de errores se puede configurar después de obtener el Stream. Así sabrás que error te está dando la salida del comando. Eso puede ayudar a ver qué está pasando. Deberás añadir algo como esto `$errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);`

Comment: De todas formas, el Stream se debe ir llenando, así que es posible que tengas que esperar en un bucle y luego leer el Stream. Si lo haces al instante es posible que llegue vacío y por eso te salga siempre error.

Comment: Hola @Jakala , esta linea "$errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);" la pongo justo en que parte del codigo?